# Как вывести все данные из БД по нескольким параметрам одного столбца?

Tags: php

Есть задача вывести все данные из БД по нескольким параметрам одного столбца.

Допустим, нужно вывести все данные из базы, в которых параметр статус равен 5 и 4 (без запятых), это разные строки таблицы!

Comment: > Есть задача вывести все данные из БД по нескольким параметрам одного столбца?

Это вопрос, есть ли такая задача?

> допустим нужно вывести все данные из базы, в которых параметр статус равен 5 и 4 (без запятых) это разные строки таблицы!

Если есть таблица с полем status и надо выбрать все записи, у которых в поле status стоит или 4, или 5, то это простой SELECT с WHERE:

    SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE status = 4 OR status = 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status=4 OR status=5
```

Выведет все строки таблицы со всеми колонками, в которых поле status=4 или 5.

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я себя почувствовал тупым =) точно же.